# Как сделать редирект с http на https через .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, http-redirect

Воспользовался таким решением:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Однако при редиректе получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, на подобный результат влияют другие правила .htaccess?

Конструкцию подключаю здесь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
RewriteRule (.*) https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```